# Why strcat causing segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Can anyone explain to me why the following code causing segmentation fault? buff should be long enough to hold 128 characters.

```
int main () {
    char buff[16384];
    char buff2[128];
    sprintf(buff2, "MinPer(PatternName_Equal27_xxxxxxx_MasterPatSetup.PatternName_Equal27_xxxxxxx__default_WFT___WFTRef.ActualT0Period.UserPeriod_2_1)" );
    strcat(buff, buff2);
    std::cout << buff2 << endl;
    std::cout << buff << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because `buff` is uninitalized garbage, and `strcat()`ing something on top of garbage just results in more garbage, that completely scribbles all over the stack, corrupting the return address, and generally making a big mess.

Comment: Because the string is 130-characters long. It does not fit into `buff2` to begin with.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - good catch.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE].  That said, I think this question has been unfairly down-voted.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers and recommendation of how to ask a question.

Comment: a good practice is always using `strncat` instead of `strcat`. Also for `strncmp` and `strncpy` etc. In this way instead of doing operation until a null character it advanced until specfied length. So you could prevent many of bugs.

Answer (score 11):

You have two major problems:

1. Your `sprintf` is shoving 131 bytes (130 characters plus a `NUL`) into a 128 byte buffer, meaning three unrelated stack bytes are getting overwritten with garbage. You need a larger buffer, or a smaller initialization string.
2. You call `strcat` to append said 131 characters to a buffer with undefined contents (no `NUL` to indicate where the string being concatenated to ends). This is trivially fixable, by either zero-initializing all of `buff` (`char buff[16384] = {0};`) or by inserting the `NUL` in the first byte (which is all you really need) adding `buff[0] = '\0';` just before you `strcat` to it. Equivalently, you could replace `strcat` (which assumes a string to concatenate new data to exists in the destination) with `strcpy` (which ignores the existing contents of the destination) to avoid the problem.

Basically, your code is full of undefined behavior and buffer overruns. Given you're using C++, can I recommend just using `std::string` to avoid the hassle of C strings?

Answer (score 3):

`buff` is uninitialized. It needs to contain a *null terminated string* so that `strcat` knows where to begin the concatenation. One way to do this is with `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(buff, ""); // initialize with empty null terminated string
strcat(buff, buff2); // add to it
```

Answer (score 1):

strcat needs 'dest' to be a string ending with '\0'. So buff should be initialized manually.